# Why did the controllerName get the value Index.php instead of Index without .php at the end

Tags: php, controller, get

code from **index.php**

```
<?php

$controllerName = isset($_GET['controller']) ? ucfirst($_GET['controller']) : 'Index';
echo 'php file[Controller] = '.$controllerName.'<br/>';

$actionName = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : 'index';
echo 'function [action] = '.$actionName.'<br/>';

include_once '../myshop.local/controllers/' .$controllerName. 'Controller.php';

?>
```

Comment: What's the output of $_GET['controller']?

Comment: Index.php  and i need Index

Comment: What's the exact output of running this script?

Comment: php file[Controller] = Index.php
function [action] = test

Warning: include_once(../myshop.local/controllers/Index.phpController.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop.local\index.php on line 10

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '../myshop.local/controllers/Index.phpController.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop.local\index.php on line 10
full name = testAction

Comment: Failed opening '../myshop.local/controllers/Index.phpController.php'

Comment: problem in Index.phpController.php instead IndexController.php

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with your framework but it seems that the query string for the controller includes the extension (.php), so the value of `$_GET['controller']` would be `index.php`.

Therefore, i'll advise you to handle this situation by following:

1. Is the $_GET['controller'] contains the extension? ([`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php))
2. If so, remove it. ([`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php))

Code:

```
$extension_incl = strpos($controllerName, '.php');

if ($extension_incl !== false) {
  $controllerName = str_replace('.php', '', $controllerName);
}
```